# Regex String URL

Tags: javascript, regex

#### Example

```
 1. http://ad.ly/123411/http://blabalba.com/adaf
 2. http://ad.ly/142145/http://blabal.com/adf34
```

> how to replace front String http://ad.ly/1246721/ use js regex
>   into http://blabalbal.com/adaf

get this http://blabalbal.com/adaf

Answer (score 2):

The regexp required is `http:\/\/adf_.ly\/\d+\/(.+)`

```
var str = 'http://adf_.ly/1246721/http://prefiles.com/files';
var re = /http:\/\/adf_.ly\/\d+\/(.+)/;
var newstr = re.exec(str)[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just take the part you're interested in using `lookahead directive`:

```
s = 'http://adf_.ly/123411/http://blabalba.com/adaf';
u = s.match(/(?!^)http:\/\/.+?$/)[0];
//=> http://blabalba.com/adaf
```